# whmcs invoice in new tab

Tags: javascript, php, whmcs

I want to open the invoices of whmcs in a new tab or a popup window.
The biggest part of this problem is solved but one thing remains a problem. I used some js to open up the invoice in a new tab, but on the original page, after opening the invoice, it also loads and returns a 404. The invoice opens without any problems.

This is the js

```
            <script>
            function OpenInNewTab(url) {
                var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
                win.focus();
                 }
            </script>
```

this is the code to call the invoices and display it in a table. note: this is a smarty .tpl

```
<tr onclick="clickableSafeRedirect(event, OpenInNewTab('viewinvoice.php?id={$invoice.id}'), false)">
                    <td>{$invoice.invoicenum}</td>
                    <td><span class="hidden">{$invoice.normalisedDateCreated}</span>{$invoice.datecreated}</td>
                    <td><span class="hidden">{$invoice.normalisedDateDue}</span>{$invoice.datedue}</td>
                    <td>{$invoice.total}</td>
                    <td><span class="label status status-{$invoice.statusClass}">{$invoice.status}</span></td>
                    <td class="responsive-edit-button" style="display: none;" >
                        <a href="viewinvoice.php?id={$invoice.id}" class="btn btn-block btn-info" >
                            {$LANG.manageproduct}
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

I added the OpenInNewTab in this line

```
<tr onclick="clickableSafeRedirect(event, OpenInNewTab('viewinvoice.php?id={$invoice.id}'), false)">
```

and this was the original code

```
<tr onclick="clickableSafeRedirect(event, viewinvoice.php?id={$invoice.id}, false)">
```

Thanks in advance!!

EDIT: I tried to merge the clickableSafeRedirect function with the OpenInNewTab function, this resulted in an empty tab with the invoice loaded on the original page.

This is the clickableSafeRedirect function

```
function clickableSafeRedirect(clickEvent, target, newWindow) {

    var eventSource = clickEvent.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
    var eventParent = clickEvent.target.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase();
    var eventTable = clickEvent.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    if (jQuery(eventTable).hasClass('collapsed')) {
        // This is a mobile device sized display, and datatables has triggered folding
        return false;
    }
    if(eventSource != 'button' && eventSource != 'a') {
        if(eventParent != 'button' && eventParent != 'a') {
            if (newWindow) {
                window.open(target);

            } else {
                window.location.href = target;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function `clickableSafeRedirect()` in WHMCS have a parameter that allows yo to open the new window instead of your custom function.

Remove your `OpenInNewTab()` function and make this:

```
clickableSafeRedirect(event, viewinvoice.php?id={$invoice.id}, true);
---------------------------------------------------------------^^^^
```

Setting true in the third parameter open in new window. Look at the code in whmcs. The definition of the function is:

```
function clickableSafeRedirect(clickEvent, target, newWindow)
```